# Is it usual to use YouTube videos showcasing real life experiences/interviews for research?

Tags: independent-researcher, social-media

I have a research project concentrating on the long-term outcomes of using local medicinal plants among rural communities. I see many YT videos on this topic from many different cultures e.g. short interviews with rural households in Kenya. Being able to gather and highlight these experiences could make a great contribution to the research. But I am not sure whether public interviews on YT are considered as open-licensed or restricted.
So any suggestion on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but if I understand it correctly, it seems a terrible idea and a recipe for bad research: you would have no control at all on your sample.

Comment: Agree with @MassimoOrtolano. What you are seeing is anecdotal at best and biased toward "usefulness" at worst. It also seems off-topic as it deals with the content of research. See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: But welcome to the site in any case.